# Solr query version issue: Invalid version or the data in not in 'javabin' format

Tags: java, solr, version

As part of a recent project, our Solr Search engine was upgraded to 5.0.0. The program which runs the client works fine in production/qa, but when I run the it on my local system, I get this error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid version or the data in not in 'javabin' format
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinCodec.java:99)
```

This exception is from apache-solr-solrj-1.4.1.jar, which i would've thought needs to be replaced. But when I check the (running) production code, the same jar file is there.

However, the java version on the production server has been upgraded to java version "1.7.0_79". On my local system, I'm pointing at a 1.6 jre from STS/Eclipse. If I change to 1.7, I start getting those 51 vs. 50 class version error in a different part of the program, indicating that there's an issue with converting to 1.7, although again it doesn't seem to be a problem on the production server.

I have tested that the solr server is running correctly via the web client. It returns the data in Json format.

One question is I have is, what does it mean when it says "invalid version or the data isn't in javabin format"? I guess it means, it may be in javabin format, but not the version of it that's expected, or it's in a different format like XML or Json. But, I'm not clear which of the two is the problem, for one thing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

All set. I did update to Java 1.7, by pointing to a JRE - plus,  there was some code from an included library that had gotten updated that I hadn't pulled in.

Answer (score 0):

Its a problem of version support. Same error i solved in solr 4.6.1 by replacing previous jar by solr-solrj4.9.0.jar. If you still facing same error you need to upgrade your java version. Remember one thing same version of solr-core.jar need to be there for successful execution.